# Minecraft Plugin MYSQL connection problem with getting player

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, minecraft

I have a problem with my Minecraft plugin. The problem is when im trying to get player's nickname from database (column called "nick") that is suppose to compare to the player that joined and its not working. There is also a column called "zalogowany" that determines either a player is logged in or not. if "tak" and he moved its suppose to say "Player Logged in" when he makes any move but if there is "nie" as a value then its suppose to say "Player not logged in". There is no error poping out in console but when player moves and there is "tak" its not broadcasting anything. If i didnt put any important information in please say in comments its my 2nd post here but first with minecraft plugin.
Here my code:

```
    @EventHandler
public void onMove(PlayerMoveEvent ev) {
    MySQLE.connect();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        Player p = ev.getPlayer();
        ps = MySQLE.con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM gracze");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            if(rs.getString("nick") == p.getName()) {
                if(rs.getString("zalogowany") == "tak") {
                    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("Player Logged in");
                }else if(rs.getString("zalogowany") == "nie") {
                    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("Player is not logged in!");
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MySQLE.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: You cannot compare string content using `==` so those cases never get reached. Use String#equals().

Comment: I get error when I try "if(String#.equals(p.getName())) {" instead of the "if(rs.getString("nick") == p.getName()) {" @MrBorder

Comment: Not String#.equals. String#equals() means the equals method from the String object like:
`if (rs.getString("nick").equals(p.getName())`. 

You don't check string content using `==` You check it using equals. @Sawio2001

Comment: I fixed that and still not working. its just not broadcasting message on move even when "zalogowany" is set to "tak"
 `public void onMove(PlayerMoveEvent ev) {
  MySQLE.connect();
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  try {
   Player p = ev.getPlayer();
   ps = MySQLE.con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM gracze");
   ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
   while(rs.next()) {
    if(rs.getString("nick").equals(p.getName())) {
     if(rs.getString("zalogowany").equals("tak")) {
      Bukkit.broadcastMessage("test");
     }else if(rs.getString("zalogowany").equals("nie")) {
`

Comment: @MrBorder do you know why?